# How to create a json array in dynamodb?

Tags: arrays, json, amazon-dynamodb

For instance, I have an json array like:

```
[
{
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00"
},
{
    color: "blue",
    value: "#00f"
},
{
    color: "cyan",
    value: "#0ff"
}]
```

Seems the dynamoDB recommendation is to add a "key-name" to the array.

```
[
color1: {
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00"
},
color2: {
    color: "blue",
    value: "#00f"
},
color3: {
    color: "cyan",
    value: "#0ff"
}]
```

Is there a different way to add an json array into DynamoDB?

Comment: Hi, DynamoDB itself store the data in JSON format. When you retrieve the data they give you in key value pair. I would suggest looking into the data type they support . Let's say currently you wnt to store color array then you can create the List type attribute into the table.

Answer (score 4):

Couple of clarifications first:

- Your statement, 'Seems the dynamoDB recommendation is to add a "key-name" to the array', is not true.
- notionquest@'s suggestion of converting payload to JSON, using a custom marshaller, would work, but isn't necessary.

DynamoDB supports List data type natively. Check [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes).

If you are using the [DynamoDBMapper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html) library in Java, you can do something like:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="...")
public class ... {  // POJO
  private List<Color> colors;

  ... // Getters and setters

  @DynamoDBDocument
  public static class Color {
    private String name;
    private String value;

    ... // Getters and setters
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AWS-SDK Java, then you can marshall your complex object to store it as JSON in DynamoDB. Please refer the below blog for more details. Specifically, I am referring to:-

```
@DynamoDBMarshalling (marshallerClass = PhoneNumberMarshaller.class)
class PhoneNumberJSONMarshaller extends JsonMarshaller<PhoneNumber>
{ }
```

https://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx1K7U34AOZBLJ2/Using-Custom-Marshallers-to-Store-Complex-Objects-in-Amazon-DynamoDB